# Do I have to merge the 2 branches?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-merge

I have a branch named student-log-in which has been merged to main. I would like to change the user interface so it's more appealing on the website so I've created another branch called user-interface. However I want to be able to have access to the code which displays the student log in page and was wondering what I have to do. I assumed since I merged it to main it would be accessible to user-interface. Do I have to merge the two branches?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the main branch, pull to make sure you have the student-log-in branch that you merged to main.

Then if you create a new branch from there, it will already have access to all the commits you made on the branch student-log-in.

e.g.

```
git checkout main
git pull origin main
git checkout -b user-interface
```

IF you have already created the branch user-interface (before pulling main) then you can still checkout and pull main, and then checkout branch user-interface, and merge main into user-interface.

e.g.

```
git checkout main
git pull origin main
git checkout user-interface
git merge main
```